# In Splunk, how do I efficiently map data from separate searches into the same row?

Tags: logging, splunk, splunk-query

My problem is that we have some logging inconsistencies and I'm trying to compensate by filling in the gaps of missing data amongst our logs messages.

For example, say I want these values in a single table entry:

- request id
- session id
- application id
- customer id

The "request id" value makes the most appearances across the log messages, but each other piece of data is not in the same log message as the others (i.e. you won't find "session id" and "application id" in the same message).

And say that "customer id" is only seen alongside "application id" and not "request id".

So I'm left to try to piece this puzzle together, however I've found joins to be incredibly finicky and not well-suited for a situation like this (it just looks awful and doesn't seem to fit this task well).

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What *IS* the common field across these events? IP address? Hostname? Something else?

Something along the lines of this will get you started:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp ip=*
| fields - _raw
| fields _time ip req_id session_id app_id cust_id
| fillnull value="n/a" req_id session_id app_id cust_id
| stats count by ip req_id session_id app_id cust_id
| fields - count
```

or, perhaps:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp ip=*
| fields - _raw
| fields _time ip req_id session_id app_id cust_id
| stats values(*) as * by ip
```

Comment: "request_id" is the most common overlap between the log messages, but of those fields that I listed, "customer_id" does not appear in any log messages alongside "request_id".  So for that field, I would instead need to map it to "application_id".  "application_id" is seen in some log messages with "request_id".